# Ng-Zorro-antd failing to compile after adding "ng add ng-zorro-antd"

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

After adding `ng-zorro-antd`, project is not compiling and giving errors.

1. `ng new PROJECT_NAME`
2. `cd PROJECT_NAME`
3. `ng add ng-zorro-antd`

My configurations are:
`Angular CLI: 16.2.6 Node: 18.18.2 Package Manager: npm 9.8.1 OS: win32 x64`

`Angular: 16.2.10`
 `animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms`
 `platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router`

`Package                         Version`

`@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.6`
`@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.6`
`@angular-devkit/core            16.2.6`
`@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.6`
`@angular/cli                    16.2.6`
`@schematics/angular             16.2.6`
`rxjs                            7.8.1`
`typescript                      5.1.6`
`zone.js                         0.13.3`

I created a new project and added `ng add ng-zorro-antd`. It is not compiling the project. Giving the following error at compile.

> 

```
`Build at: 2023-10-19T18:34:17.236Z - Hash: d997af026ed5bf61 - Time: 38719ms

./src/theme.less - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):`


`@import './themes/@{root-entry-name}.less'`;
`@import (inline) '../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';`
^
Less resolver error:
`'../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css'` wasn't found. Tried - C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css,..\..\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css

Webpack resolver error details:
resolve `'../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css'` in `'C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\style'`
  using description file: C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\package.json (relative path: ./style)
    using description file: C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css)
      no extension
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css doesn't exist
      .less
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css.less doesn't exist
      .css
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css.css doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css doesn't exist

Webpack resolver error missing:
undefined


      Error in C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\style\patch.less (line 2, column 0)

./src/theme.less?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


`@import './themes/@{root-entry-name}.less';`
`@import (inline) '../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';`
^
Less resolver error:
`'../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css'` wasn't found. Tried - C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css,..\..\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css

Webpack resolver error details:
resolve `'../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css'` in `'C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\style'`
  using description file: C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\package.json (relative path: ./style)
    using description file: C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css)
      no extension
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css doesn't exist
      .less
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css.less doesn't exist
      .css
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css.css doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\node_modules\@angular\cdk\overlay-prebuilt.css doesn't exist

Webpack resolver error missing:
undefined


      Error in C:\Users\sunil\OneDrive\Documents\Angular Projects\angular6\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\style\patch.less (line 2, column 0)



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4400, open your browser on http://localhost:4400/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: 16.2.2 Just released 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-zorro-antd?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in `ng-zorro-antd` 16.2.1 which, according to this [Github discussion](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/pull/8132), will soon be fixed in version 16.2.2.

You can either wait for it to be fixed, or downgrade `ng-zorro-antd` (15.1.0) and `angular` (15.2.10).